# Parsing a string with scanf with 2 different delimiters in C

Tags: c

Trying to parse a string with two different delimiters.
A space, followed by 2 commas, followed by a space/newline characters.

```
scanf("%s%[^,]s%[^,]s%s", v1, v2, v3, v4);
```

For some reason, writing to the stdin a string delimited as followed "abc asc, abc abc" will generate correct result for v1 and v2. but garbage results for v3 and v4.

What might be the reason?

**EDIT:**
here is the full code

```
char v1[MAX_LENG], v2[MAX_LENG], v4[MAX_LENG], v3[MAX_LENG];

scanf("%s%[^,]%[^,]%s", v1, v2, v3, v4);
printf("%s%s%s%s", v1, v2, v3, v4);
```

and it prints
read A�

Comment: `"%s%[^,]s%[^,]s%s` --> `"%s %[^,], %s %[^,],"` ?

Comment: As it stands right now, the code you've posted can't possibly compile. Could you please cut and paste in the code you're actually using? In a case like this, it's crucial that we know we're seeing your code verbatim, and right now we clearly aren't.

Comment: edited the post and added the code

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf` before printing the value.

Comment: i already did,the return value is 2. i can't figure out why it's not reading more than 2

Comment: Because `%[^,]` read upto `,`. 1st `%s` read `abc`, 1st `%[^,]` read `" asc"`, 2nd `%[^,]` reject `,`.  this read nothing and last `%s` too.

Comment: so what do i do to make it keep on reading?

Comment: Take a look at my first comment.

Comment: wonderful thank you

Comment: personally i would use strtok.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below:

```
"%s %[^,], %s %s"
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c
$ ./a.out
abc def, hij klm   <<<<< Input
abc
def
hij
klm
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) call:

```
scanf("%s%[^,]s%[^,]s%s", v1, v2, v3, v4);
```

reads a first string up to a white space (blank, tab, etc) into `v1`; it then reads a second string (including leading white space) up to a comma into `v2`.  It then fails because the next character is a comma, but the code is scanning for an `s`.  The scan set notation is `%[…]` or `%[^…]`; it is not a modifier for the `s` conversion; it is quite separate and is complete at the `]`.  So, the first two fields are read; then the conversion fails.  So, `scanf()` returns 2 — but you weren't paying any attention to that.  You must *always* check the return from `scanf()` (or any input function) to ensure you got the result you expected.

Note that simply removing the `s` after the scan set would not be a complete solution.  The next character is a comma, so the second `%[^,]` scan set would fail; you have to provide something to read the comma.  You repeat the "`s` after scan set" bug, but if that's fixed too, then you'd be in with a fighting chance.

However, your input is claimed to be:

```
abc asc, abc abc
```

There's only one comma there.  To parse that, therefore, you'd use:

```
if (scanf("%s %[^,] , %s %s", v1, v2, v3, v4) != 4)
    …something went wrong…
```

The blank before the scan set skips any leading blanks (the three conversions `%c`, `%n` and `%[…]` do not skip leading white space; all others do).
All the other blanks could be omitted without changing the behaviour (and omitting the blank before the comma literal is [arguably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246400/parsing-a-string-with-scanf-with-2-different-delimiters-in-c/47947320?noredirect=1#comment82864660_47947320) a good idea, as [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) says — but as I stated, the blank before it does no direct harm either, at least as long as those reading the code are sufficiently experienced to know what it means).

When it comes to error reporting, it would be a lot easier if you read an entire line ([`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or perhaps POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and then parsed that with `scanf()`.  It makes good error reporting a lot easier this way.

Comment: Recommend `"%[^,] ,"` to `"%[^,],"`  Drop space - it confuses a review of the the consumption of the `','`.   Yet as you say "All the other blanks could be omitted ...".  I guess it is the idiom of `"%[^a_single_char]a_single_char"` that looks good to avoid breaking.